# How do I set git difftool context?

Tags: git, vim

What is the equivalent of diff.tool git config key that would determine the context of git difftool ? I have set my difftool to be vimdiff.

Comment: Ah! zR shows all the lines in the file. http://superuser.com/questions/198779/make-vimdiff-show-entire-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim's diff context can be changed via `diffopt`. This is a Vim option and not a git one, so it must be specified in your `.vimrc`. For example:

```
set diffopt+=context:2
```

Note that `+=` should be used instead of `=` because `diffopt` is a list.

See `:help diffopt` for more info.